# Can No Machine's Nxserver run on an ubuntu without desktop, just X11?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, x11, nomachine-nx

I am running an instance of Ubuntu on AWS uxing X11 tunneled via ssh. It runs, but is too slow. NXMachine over x11 makes it blazingly fast, in comparison.

Next step is to free up some RAM by uninstalling GNOME, the instance being tiny as it is, while still having a display. Works for x11 (but too slow to be useful), not sure how to do it for NX. Has anyone done this?

Edit: BTW, is there a way to speed up X11 other than NXMachine? If I can get fast x11, mission accomplished!

Comment: I have it under xfce.  Why not just look up the package dependencies for the package? It's called "nxclient".

Comment: Thank you - xfce might work! How much smaller is xfce vs. GNOME, RAM-wise?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_12.shtml#Install NX Free Edition for Linux to Amazon EC2 Instance Try this you have to install nxclient,nxnode and nxserver packages and then configure it for X11. The above link gives you all.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Actually, these instructions guide you through installing GNOME. I don't want GNOME.